# jquery autocomplete --- if json is empty?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i have below code for Jquery AutoComplete textbox

```
$(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "AutoCompleteFetchService.asmx/getUserNames",
            data: "{'TextBoxVal':'" + document.getElementById('txtName1').value + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data1) {
                response(data1.d);
            },
```

am getting suggestions correctly . Am trying to display `" No search found"` if no data is returned. If JSon is empty am having the below loop executed

```
if(typeof (data1.d) == 'undefined')
{
}
```

but how can i return or change to display "No data found"  in the suggestion ?

is there any easier way ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jQuery.isEmptyObject()` to check if the json is empty and then return "No data found"